# Parent-child tree hierarchy with NHibernate

Tags: nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate

I have a Group. That group can contain groups and this needs to be mapped with NHibernate. I have done this before but this time I got an existing database that does not really store the data like I would like it too.

The database looks like this:

Groups

Id

Groups_Link

ParentId
ChildId

I have no clue about how to map this?

**Edit:**

Seems like it's not that easy. One group can exist as a child to more than one group. So it should be an many-to-many association with itself I guess. Well, have yet to figure out how to do this. Any hints would be really appreciated!

**Edit:**

I thought views could help me solve the problem but there seems to be some restrictions on insert, update and delete with views that makes it difficult.

Answer (score 0):

I mapped a similar structure like:

```
<class name="Folder" lazy="false">

    <id column="Id" name="Id">
        <generator class="guid"/>
    </id>

    <property name="Name" column="FolderText"></property>
    <bag  name="Children" cascade="all" fetch="subselect" inverse="true">
        <key  column="ParentId" />
        <one-to-many class="Folder" />
    </bag>

    <many-to-one class="Folder" name="Parent" column="ParentId" insert="true" />
```

**Edit**

I am taking a total shot in the dark now since your schema is not what I've used, and now I understand why you asked this:-) Anyways here's is a thought. Please let us know if this worked of if you find another solution:

```
    <join fetch="join" table="GroupLinks">
        <key column="ChildId"></key>
        <many-to-one name="Parent" class="Folder" column="ParentId"/>
    </join>
```

I might have the relationship backwards, but this at least would get you the parent.

Comment: But that won't solve the problem with the Groups_Link table. Your mapping will work only if you have the ParentId in the Groups table if I understood it correctly? Or is it more to the last many-to-one that I missed?

Comment: Sorry your schema representation wasn't clear. I thought it was one table

Comment: I still have some things to fix before I can try out the mapping you posted. Will be in about three hours or so and I'll report the result so you know if it worked or not.

Comment: Tried it and couldn't get it to work. Well, time to go home. Maybe I'll continue later. Well, will post the result when it's done. Any more ideas would have been very appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

As you say, it's just a many-to-many that happens to have the same class on both sides of the join. 
So:

```
<class name="G.Group, G" table="GROUPS">

  <id column="Id" name="Id">
    <generator class="guid"/>
  </id>

  <set name="Parents" table="Groups_Link" cascade="save-update">
    <key column="ChildId"/>
    <many-to-many class="G.Group, G" column="ParentId"/>
  </set>

  <set name="Children" table="Groups_Link" cascade="save-update" inverse="true">
    <key column="ParentId" />
    <many-to-many class="G.Group, G" column="ChildId"/>
  </set>

</class>
```